# AS3 How to import a .dll?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, dll

Is it possible to import a .dll file into an adobe air game using Actionscript 3?

Thinking about using Discords Game API but that requires the game to import a .dll file, and I'm unsure if that's possible using adobe air and as3

Comment: You cannot do it with pure AS3, meaning you cannot build a web-based application with such a capability. You need AIR runtime and you need to build ANE (AIR Native Extension) in order to use DLL functionality: http://easynativeextensions.com/windows-tutorial-introduction/

Comment: Thanks for the lead, I have been trying to search for how to create ANE's but I haven't found anything so this is super helpful!

Comment: For anyone else looking to use a DLL's functions with AIR...  Another alternative is to just use C# to create a middleman application (command line tool). This EXE would have the DLL embedded inside. To run its functions from AIR, just run the EXE as an external Process and communicate with it via **stdIN**. Use **stdIN** to send String commands that your EXE then parses to run the relevant function.

Comment: @VC.One Would I be able to communicate both ways? Like having the EXE send data to the AIR game without it having to ask for it. And do you have any tutorials or something you could link? Would be very appreciated!

Comment: @Orbit yes you can communicate both ways. `Standard In/Out` is a feature of most programming languages that can run another app as a Process, so C# has it too. Your EXE must write the response in its std**Out** which is then received by AIR app in its std**In**, and vice-versa for other way communication. I recommend [**SharpDevelop**](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sharpdevelop/) if you don't already have a C# IDE/compiler. Try a basic test like AS3 says "hello" and then some triggered C# function says "world" back. Each side receives via its own `stdIn` and sends out data via its `stdOut`.

Comment: @VC.One I've tried to get communication working both ways for a while now. I can write from the c# app to as3, but not the other way around. Followed a lot of tutorials and tried to read from the stdin stream in c# various different ways, but it isn't working. Got any clue what I can do? I can provide pictures and so, just ask. Thanks for your help :)