# C# Console app standard input not usable by other program?

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, streamreader

```
using (Stream stdin = Console.OpenStandardInput())
        {
            using (Stream stdout = Console.OpenStandardOutput())
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                int bytes;
                while ((bytes = stdin.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    stdout.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);
                }
            }
        }
```

This code is a basic echo from the stdin to stdout, and it works when I write directly into the console. But when I try to write to the stdin using another program, in this case an AIR game using ActionScript 3, it isn't working.

I've launched the C# application using AS3's NativeProcess. It let's me start a process and access it's standard input/output. Reading from the stdout works fine, but writing to the stdin does nothing.

This is the AS3 code that writes to the stdin:
[image: The AS3 code for writing to the stdin]

I got no clue why this isn't working. I've tried several different reading methods on the C# application but nothing captures the data I send via the stdin.

The C# applications stdin:
[image: The C# applications stdin]

The C# applications stdout:
[image: The C# applications stdout]

I'd appreciate any help as to why this isn't working. Thanks!

Comment: Can you even *write* to `stdin`? In my head, `stdin` is read-only, while `stdout` and `stderr` are write only. Whenever I've wanted to glue them together I've used a pipe

Comment: The question as asked makes no sense as you can't *write* into *input* of your own app... There is remote chance you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613161/how-to-write-to-the-stdin-of-another-app - some [edit] of the post may clarify what you are looking for.

Comment: standardInput is the output to the c# application while standardOutput is the input from the c# application. That's how the NativeProcess behaves, I'll add some pictures to clarify.

Comment: Why using `writeUTF( value: "hello" );` instead of the correct `writeUTF( "hello" );`? Anyways is the problem solved by using **Net 3.5**? I'm seeing **Net 4.7** on my dev computer but haven't had a chance to try out your DLL issue yet (_eg:_ for this specific task it may really need version 3.5). I'll update when I get a chance.

Comment: @Flydog57, **Read again** it says _`"write to the stdin using another program"`_. I think you assume C# started the process, but actually the other program is running this C# exe as a child process. From AS3 docs: `process.standardInput.writeUTF("foo");` (see [**communicating with an external process**](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSb2ba3b1aad8a27b060d22f991220f00ad8a-8000.html) section) because the [**AS3 manual**](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html#standardInput) says _"Use this pipe to send data to this process."_.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Asker is not _"writing to their own program"_. This C# app will run as a child process from an AS3 app. In their shown C# code the `stdin.Read` part is reading input  sent to it by the AS3 app that started it, then for further testing Asker communicates back to the parent (AS3 app) by using `stdout.Write`. I recommended [this way to them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62906471/as3-how-to-import-a-dll#comment111369152_62906471) because its how AS3 works (see also my above comment). Please vote to re-open. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It turns out you can't do this on the current .NET framework. You have to be on **3.5 or lower**.

Here is the answer I found.
[AIR NativeProcess standardInput not connecting to app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532442/air-nativeprocess-standardinput-not-connecting-to-app)

**Edit:**
Even after changing my .NET framework to 3.5 and even 3.0, I can't get this to work. I gave up after a full day of debugging, so I instead went ahead and implemented a simple TCP client on the C# app and a server in the flash game. Works flawlessly, but a bit unnecessary.